# Realm 1.0.1 update

Tags: xcode, realm

I just updated to RealmSwift 1.0.1, Xcode 7.2.1 and my project failed with 44 errors. These are just some of them. I have tried with dynamic framework install and using cocoa pods.

RealmCollectionType.swift:

> RealmSwift/RealmCollectionType.swift:152:26: Use of undeclared type
>   'Element'

LinkingObjects.swift:

> /RealmSwift/RealmCollectionType.swift:645:21: Cannot invoke initializer for type '*AnyRealmCollection<*>' with an argument list of type '(base: C)'

List.swift:

> /RealmSwift/List.swift:507:50: Cannot convert value of type 'AnyRealmCollection' to expected argument type 'AnyRealmCollection<_>'

Results.swift:

> RealmSwift/Results.swift:418:50: Cannot convert value of type 'AnyRealmCollection' to expected argument type 'AnyRealmCollection<_>'

[image]

Comment: Which version of Realm were you using prior to updating, and which version of Xcode are you using it with?

Comment: Have you tried to delete DerivedData?

Comment: ya i deleted the derived data, no luck

Comment: Previous Realm v .96.2